# Chromebook dev mode

Tags: chromebook

I have a Chromebook 11 3180 Dell and want to activate dev mode but it is school admin controlled. will the admin control restore once I sync my school managed google account that is admin controlled?

Comment: Who is the owner of this chromebook?

Comment: I own it but its admin controlled and the admin is the school.

Comment: How is this possible, why your own book is managed by someone else?

Comment: because the school gave it to me I bought it from the school to use in school.

Answer (score 0):

If it is now 100% yours, you can ask the school to de-register it from their system.  This would not affect your use of your school email account on it.

Comment: no, I partly own it and still need it till mid-June 2021 and I want to activate developer mode but I am worried it will de-register it from their system and the question is will it?

Comment: Is the admin control on my google account or my Chromebook because it is on both.

Comment: The school's control of the device is tied to the hardware itself, nothing to do with which Google account you use.  Almost for sure you won't be able to enter developer mode unless you can convince their IT department to allow it (pretty much 0% chance of that because it's a security issue).